# Rotar posicion array php

Tags: php, html, array, bucle-for

Basicamente tengo que mover una posicion del array (la posicion 0 a la 1, la 1 a la 2, asi sucesivamente hasta la ultima posicion que se traslada a la primera)
Ejemplo:
Array= 1/5/7/9/14/12
Cambio de posicion= 12/1/5/7/9/14
La variable $num, la uso para saber el numero de posiciones que tendra el array.

```
<?php

$num=$_POST['num'];

echo 'Contenido del array: ';

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){

    $numeros[]=rand(0,100);

    echo $numeros[$i].' | ';

}

echo "<br> <br>";

$ultimo=$numeros[$num-1];

echo 'Nuestro array rotado: ';
for($i=0;$i<$num-1;$i++){
          $numeros[0]=$ultimo;
      echo $numeros[$i]=$numeros[$i].' | ';
} 
echo "<br> <br>";

?>
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas

Answer (score 2):

La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
$nums = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Retiras el último elemento del arreglo.
$last = array_pop($nums);
// Lo insertas en la primera posición.
array_unshift($nums, $last);

// Imprimes su contenido (con fines depurativos).
print_r($nums); // [5,1,2,3,4]
```

---

Ahora que si quisieras hacerlo reutilizable, encapsula la funcionalidad:

```
$nums = [1,2,3,4,5];

/**
 * Recorre los elementos un lugar a la derecha.
 *
 * @see https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/221975/729
 * @param array $array
 */
function array_move_rigth(&$array)
{
    $last = array_pop($array);
    array_unshift($array, $last);
}

array_move_rigth($nums);
array_move_rigth($nums);

print_r($nums); // [4,5,1,2,3]
```

**Documentación:**

- [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)
- [array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este código:

```
$num=$_POST['num'];
echo 'Contenido del array: ';

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
    $numeros[]=rand(0,100);
    echo $numeros[$i].' | ';
}

echo "<br> <br>";

//Creamos un array auxiliar con los mismos valores
$aux = $numeros;

//Ahora los intercambiamos en nuestro array original
$numeros[0] = $aux[$num-1];
$numeros[$num-1] = $aux[0];

echo 'Nuestro array rotado: ';
for($i=0;$i<=$num-1;$i++){
    echo $numeros[$i].' | ';
} 
echo "<br> <br>";
```

Comment: Lo que busco no es invertir todo el contenido del array, solo colocar en la posicion 0 el valor de la ultima posicion del array (sin funciones)                                                                     Ejemplo: Array= 1/5/7/9/14/12 Cambio de posicion= 12/1/5/7/9/14

Comment: Disculpa, entendí mal tu pregunta, ya edité mi respuesta en base a tus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas una variable temporal para guardar el valor que vas a sobre-escribir.  Algo asi:

```
$num=6;

echo 'Contenido del array: ';

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){

    $numeros[]=rand(0,100);

    echo $numeros[$i].' | ';

}

echo "<br> <br>";


echo 'Nuestro array rotado: '; 
$temp = $numeros[$num-1];

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
    $temp2=$numeros[$i];
    $numeros[$i]=$temp;
    $temp=$temp2;

      echo $numeros[$i].' | ';
} 
echo "<br> <br>";
```